# Finite abelian groups whose subgroups of the same order are all isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am trying to find describe a finite abelian group whose subgroups of the same order are isomorphic. That is to say, if $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of $G$ with $|H|=|K|$, then $H\cong K$.

My progress so far:

Let us first consider the case when $G$ is an abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$. By the fundamental theorem,

$$G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{e_1}}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^{e_2}}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^{e_k}}$$

where $\sum_{j=1}^k e_k=n$. We claim that no exponent $e_i$ exceeds 1. Indeed, if there were two summands $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{e_1}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{e_2}}$ such that $e_1,e_2>1$, then we can find subgroups (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_p$, which are of the same order yet not isomorphic.

Hence if $G$ is a $p$-group of order $p^n$, it is either cyclic or of the form $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$.

**Question 1:** Did I account for all possible cases? I concluded that $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ works because the diagonal subgroup is of order $p$, which is unique.

In the general case, we know at least that if $|G|=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, then $G$ must be either of the form $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}}\times\cdots \times\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{e_k}}$, or $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}^{e_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_k}^{e_k}$. I suspect that these are all possible options.

**Question 2:** Did I account for all possible cases in the general case? I honestly doubt it, but I cannot substantiate my ominous hunch...

Comment: The first part of your proof (for $p$-groups) is all right. (Except perhaps the comment about the diagonal subgroup, which I don't think is relevant. It is true that $Z_p^n$ has this property though. Try to think how to prove it.)

Comment: For the second question, you are restricting yourself too much. As long as each Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ has the property, then so will $G$. (You can probably figure out how to prove that this is necessary and sufficient.) For example, $Z_9\times Z_2^2$ has the property, but it does not fit in either of your cases. (In other words, each Sylow subgroup has to be cyclic or elementary abelian, but these choices can be made independently for each prime.)

Comment: verret, thanks for your comment. Now I see what I was missing.

Comment: BTW, does the proof go like this: Since every abelian group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, any subgroup, which must be abelian, hence is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, must be of the form $H_1\times H_2\times \cdots \times H_k$ where each $H_i$ is a subgroup of a Sylow subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What about the group $\Bbb Z_8\times \Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: Elliot G, take $\mathbb{Z}_2\leq\mathbb{Z}_8$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\leq \mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, having order 4. This is the Klein 4-group. Take now $\mathbb{Z}_4\leq \mathbb{Z}_8$. They are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using the structure theorem. Firstly, as you've said, either each $p_i$-torsion of $G$ is a sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ or isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$. This is because in any other case, we would have two $p_i$-subgroups with one having cardinality *strictly* greater than $p_i$, from which we conclude that there are subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$. We are then left to analyse these two cases, for each $p_i$-torsion.

Let's also note that if the condition holds individually for each $p_i$-torsion of $G$, then if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, once again by the structure theorem we have that

$$
H \simeq \bigoplus_{i = 1}^k H[p_i] \quad , \quad K \simeq \bigoplus_{i = 1}^k K[p_i]
$$

and taking cardinals and using that $|H| = |K|$ and the fact that each $p_i$-torsion has cardinality equal to a power of $p_i$, by uniqueness of factorization in the integers, $|H[p_i]| = |K[p_i]|$ for all $i$. Since $H[p_i] = H \cap G[p_i]$ and $K[p_i] = K \cap G[p_i]$ are subgroups of $G[p_i]$ with the same cardinality, they would be isomorphic, from which we can conclude $H \simeq K$.

This reduces the problem to the exact same question, but restricted to each $p_i$-torsion: the condition is trivially necessary, and by the previous observation, also sufficient.

It is clear that $G[p_i] = \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$ verifies the condition, since it has exactly one subgroup of cardinality $p_i^s$ with $0 \leq s \leq e_i$.

The other case is $G[p_i] = (\mathbb{Z}_{p_i})^{e_i}$, which is also a possible outcome since any non-trivial group will be isomorphic to copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$. In effect, by the structure theorem, any subgroup of $G[p_i]$ is  a sum of $p_i$-groups, and since every nonzero element of $G[p_i]$ has order $p_i$ each is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$.

In conclusion, if $G$ is an abelian group with all subgroups of equal cardinality being isomorphic and $|G| = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, then

$$
G \simeq H_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus H_k
$$

with $H_i \simeq (\mathbb{Z}_{p_i})^{e_i}$ or $H_i \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$ for each $i \in [k]$.